# How to get element width on load?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events

I wrote a slider control in JavaScript and have some concerns about it. Script is initialized on `window.onload` and transforms all elements having class *slider* to sliders.
For example:

```
<div id="hueSlider" class="slider" min="0" max="360" value="240"></div>
```

Problem is when `document.load` event is fired elements are not rendered yet, so I can't compute slider handle position without having width of the slider. I made a workaround that creates an timer for each slider that checks if slider has non-zero width then sets handle position and removes itself.

But that's very ugly solution. Do you have an idea how to do it in the proper way?

Comment: Are you creating the content dynamically with JavaScript? If not, your elements should be rendered "onload".

Comment: @JanDvorak Thanks. I had those mixed up. I'll delete my comment as it is unconstructive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkLoad()
{
     if (window.onLoad)
     {
          // you can call your statements in here
     } else {
          setTimeout('checkLoad();', 1000)
     }
}
```

Another hack you can try is:

```
    if (window.addEventListener){

       window.addEventListener('load', ready, false)

    } else if (window.attachEvent) {

      window.attachEvent('onload', ready)
    }
```

**EDIT:**

if both of the above methods are not working, try the one below it should be fool proof and if that does not work. there might be something else wrong in your code:

```
function makeDoubleDelegate(function1, function2) {
    return function() {
        if (function1)
            function1();
        if (function2)
            function2(); //call your get slider width statements in here.
    }
}

window.onload = makeDoubleDelegate(window.onload, myNewFunction );
```

The logic behind this is, The makeDoubleDelegate() function would be put in the first JS file, ready for invokation any time. What it does is accept two functions as arguments, checks to see if they exist, and if so, return an anonymous function containing valid, existing functions.

The first time that window.onload is called, window.onload itself is undefined, so what gets returned is an anonymous function with only myNewFunction() inside. On subsequent window.onload assignments, window.onload does exist, so whatever it holds will be wrapped up with the new function. And so the list grows.

Comment: That's a terrible way to set up a timeout. Never use `setTimeout` with a string for the function

Comment: Why are you calling the latter one a "hack"?

Comment: its kinda of like a unoffical way to check window.onLoad, thats why used the term hack. your welcome to edit it and use correct terminology i am not good at english

Comment: As I've said in the first post I already use timer to set width and this solution is unsatisfactory. Also window.onload event still returns 0 for element's clientWidth.

Comment: are you using Iframes in your webpage?

Comment: @Prakash Chennupati, No there is no iframes.

Comment: @BlaskPoranka I edited my post, and proposed a new idea. that should do the trick or else there might be something else wrong in your code causing the problem.

Comment: @Prakash Chennupati, turns out all of the proposed solutions was right. There was an issue in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use this:

```
window.onload = function(){
    // Access elements in here
};
```

Or this way:

```
if(document.addEventListener) {
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        // Access elements in here for modern browsers
    }, false);
} else {
    document.attachEvent("onreadystatechange", function(){
        if(document.readyState === "complete") {
            // Access elements in here for older browsers
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: OP said `onload` is too soon. I guess this rules out `DOMContenttLoaded` as well.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak, you are right `DOMContenttLoaded` is also called before rendering document. This answer solves nothing.